# Why Build is needed?

Tags: java, maven, build

I am highly confused as why Build is needed in a java project.

I am new to Java. I have created a Java project which creates volume file.
I have run this code on my machine and created a JAR file and batch file which executes this JAR. 
Now who ever needs it, I hand over the JAR file along with .bat file and it is good to go.

Where some one asks me source code, I give them via SVN.

In this process I couldn't relate what BUILD means and where it is actually needed? And why we need build tool like Maven  (I know what maven is but can't relate)
I can easily share my JAR files and libraries with anyone who needs it.

Comment: How do you go from "source" to "Jar" - there's a step in that would "compile" and "archive/jar" the code - this is the build step and may contain a number of required steps, like obtaining additional/dynamic resources

Comment: How quaint that you code does not depend upon various versions of other peoples code

Comment: That might work well if you have a only a limited number of people you would like to offer that...The question is if you have: Say 1 Million other people who like to have it? How would you handle it than? Sending EMail, making a server where people can download it? The last thing is the basic idea of the central repository. You publish your "jar" there and everyone on the world can use it...And of course not to forget. your jar/lib also needs dependencies or in other words libraries it is using? How you handle that?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_build

Answer (score 0):

Maven offers a whole lot of different services. Those are the most obvious ones:

- Dependendy management: A big project usually needs a lot of different dependencies. Maven offers a smart mecanism to manage them, using remote and local repositories
- Compilation: Your different java files need to be compiled as class files
- Testing: Maven is able to play automated tests
- Assembling of archives: those class files may need to be stored in jar or war files in order to be usable, often alongside other resources
- Deployment: Maven can deploy your archives, for example in the repositories, so other projects using your codes will see your changes

Of course, you can customize those steps in order to adapt them to your needs, run scripts, for example.